# Change state of Bootstrap button when clicked

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a signup form for a newsletter, that I have nested inside a modalbox. Everything is working, but the user experience are really bad. Therefore I would like to add the following function.

When a person sign up with name and e-mail and click "Sign me up", I would like the button is changing to red and says "Close" instead. Since the form is from mailchimp, I *cannot* change the `<input type="submit" value="Signup" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button btn btn-success"></input>` to a button instead.

Is it possible to do this?

There is a working demo here of the signupform. At the moment the button is turning red after a signup, but I would like the button to say close instead:

[Demopage](http://vouzalis.dk/mailchimp-form-test.html)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<div class="mk row">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="col-sm-12 margin_bottom">
            <div class="hover11 column">
                <figure>
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#nyhedsbrev-tilmelding">
                      <img src="https://dohanews.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/headline.png" alt="Sign up for our newsletter" class="img-responsive"></img>
                    </a>
                </figure>
            </div>
            <div class="modal fade" id="nyhedsbrev-tilmelding" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div id="mc_embed_signup">
                            

    <form action="https://zalis.us17.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=3be651219436ee0f217f040a5&amp;id=d07c036d2e" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
 <h2>Subscribe to our mailing list</h2>
<div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk">*</span> indicates required</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
 <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
</label>
 <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
 <label for="mce-FNAME">First Name </label>
 <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="" id="mce-FNAME">
</div>

 <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
  <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
  <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
 </div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_3be651219436ee0f217f040a5_d07c036d2e" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
    </div>
</form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="inner-wrapper bottom-left"></div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you will need some JS here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add onclick atribute executing the staff you want:

```
 <input type="submit" value="Signup" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button btn btn-success" onclick="this.value='close'; this.style.backgroundColor='red';"></input>
```

Or using js selector:

```
<script>


 let $input = document.getElementById('mc-embedded-subscribe')
  $input.addEventListener('click', function (){
    this.value= "close"
    this.backgroundColor= "red"
  })
</script>
```

Comment: it's better to consider the submit event, because we can use Enter to submit the form

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I can see now the problem is that the form action is opening a new window, instead of stating in the modal box. I am gonna give a link to a demo in 5 minutes.

Comment: I just made a demo. I cannot see that the script a triggered? http://vouzalis.dk/mailchimp-form-test.html. I actually do not think it is possible to change the mailchimp button how it is now?

Comment: Thank you again. Yes of course, I made a pen here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VBNLwb

Comment: If your attempting to change the text in the button, you'll have to change value attribute instead of textContent:

const btn = document.querySelector('#mc-embedded-subscribe');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
   btn.style.background = 'red';
   btn.value = 'Close';
   btn.classList.add('closeBtn');
});

Comment: Hm pretty cool, I can see your solution almost is working. The only thing is that the close button is not closing the modalbox, or is it just me? http://vouzalis.dk/mailchimp-form-test.html. I updated the site with your code, and the codepen to.

Comment: Try adding a second event listener that executes the function in charge of closing the modal. Something like:
`
 const btn = document.querySelector('#mc-embedded-subscribe');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
   btn.style.background = 'red';
  //  btn.textContent = 'Close';
   btn.value = 'Close';
   btn.classList.add('closeBtn');
   btn.addEventListener('click', () =>{
   
    // Here you closs the modal
   })
});
`

Comment: Hm Do you have time for set the code in your answer? I have a quite hard time understand the code :-/

Answer (score 0):

Can you add another class to the input? What exactly is your problem? I'm sure you already know how this would be done

```
const btn = document.querySelector('#mc-embedded-subscribe');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
   btn.style.background = 'red';
   btn.textContent = 'Close';
   btn.classList.add('closeBtn');
});
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your suggestion. I have just made a demo of the signup form. You can see what the problem is here. When you sign up, the button is turning red. I would like the button should say close instead. I am not quite sure if it is possible with the Mailchimp forms. http://vouzalis.dk/mailchimp-form-test.html

Answer (score -1):

use JQuery

```js
$('#mc-embedded-subscribe').click(function(){

      $('#mc-embedded-subscribe').val("close");
      $('#mc-embedded-subscribe').removeClass("btn-success");
      $('#mc-embedded-subscribe').addClass("btn-danger");

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<div class="mk row">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="col-sm-12 margin_bottom">
            <div class="hover11 column">
                <figure>
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#nyhedsbrev-tilmelding">
                      <img src="https://dohanews.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/headline.png" alt="Sign up for our newsletter" class="img-responsive"></img>
                    </a>
                </figure>
            </div>
            <div class="modal fade" id="nyhedsbrev-tilmelding" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div id="mc_embed_signup">
                                <form action="#" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" >
                                    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
                                        <h2>Signup for our newsletter</h2>
                                        <div class="mc-field-group">
                                            <label for="mce-FNAME">Name </label>
                                            <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="" id="mce-FNAME"></input>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="mc-field-group">
                                            <label for="mce-EMAIL">E-mail adress  <span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
                                            <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL"></input>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="mc-field-group input-group" style="display:none;">
                                            <strong>Lande grupper</strong>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li>
                                                    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="group[7][1]" id="mce-group[7]-7-0"></input>
                                                    <label for="mce-group[7]-7-0">DK</label>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                        <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true">
                                            <input type="text" name="b_c9e771e6f8adb066a0713eb0a_6e9f7d0e57" tabindex="-1"></input>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="clear">
                                            <input type="submit" value="Signup" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button btn btn-success"></input>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="inner-wrapper bottom-left"></div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```